# Python request getting No connection adapters were found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

can I do urlprase and pass it to request like below? 
URL I'm passing is `https://server1:8089`

```
url = urlparse(args.URL)

def rest():
    url = {
        'scheme': 'https',
        'host': url.netloc,
        'port': url.port if url.port else 8089,
        'path': '/services/search/distributed/peers',
        'http_auth': (user + ":" + password),
        'use_ssl': True,
        'verify_certs': True,
        'ca_certs': certifi.where()
    }
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    payload = {
        "name": "test",
        "remoteUsername": user,
        "remotePassword": password
    }
    try:
        re = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print(re.text)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        exit(1)
```

**Error**

```
No connection adapters were found for '{'scheme': 'https', 'host': 'server1', 'port': 8089, 'path': '/services/search/distributed/peers', 'http_auth': 'user:pass', 'use_ssl': True, 'verify_certs': True, 'ca_certs': 'C:\\Users\\User1\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi\\cacert.pem'}'
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to pass urlparse to request, I was able to pass Url directly without a urlparse works just fine. but I want to do it with urlparse

```
url = http://xxxx.com:8089/services/search/distributed/peers
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `re = requests.post(http://xxxx.com:8089/services/search/distributed/peers, data=payload, headers=headers)` and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

The python `requests` library takes `url` in a plain `string` format. You cannot pass it a `dictionary` of individual url components.